Is it possible to get this grid or flexbox layout in css?
So I want to create a grid or flexbox layout which looks something like this
.
So all of the data inside each box of the image is dynamic so i am not sure about the size of every box. I am using tailwind css and plain HTML, CSS, JS.
I am creating a parent with class = grid grid-cols-3 and very column has a class = col-span-1. With this the body is evenly divided into 3 columns but the box of the next line is starting from the end of the longest element of the previous line, i.e. each row height is determined by the longest box of that row. So this is how it is turning out to be
.
I can use class = row-span-2 at the longest box but as said I don't know what will be the size of each box so I cant use class = row-span-2.
Here is what I have. Please assume Box x has all the html and css code for that desired box.
<div class=" grid grid-cols-3 m-12 gap-12 justify-center">
    <div id="post" class="max-h-fit h-fit rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
        <Box 1/>
    </div>
    <div id="post2" class="max-h-fit h-fit rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
        <Box 2/>
    </div>
    <div id="post3" class="max-h-fit h-fit rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
        <Box 3/>
    </div>
    <div id="post4" class="max-h-fit h-fit rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
        <Box 4/>
    </div>
    <div id="post5" class="max-h-fit h-fit rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
        <Box 5/>
    </div>
    <div id="pos6t" class="max-h-fit h-fit rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
        <Box 6/>
    </div>
</div>




I'll be honest, the desired result doesn't look like a grid and could probably be acheived using Flexbox

What you are looking for is called a Bento grid layout.
You can check some examples here
But coming back to your question, using CSS Columns you can achieve the layout
Check this example:
<div class="parent columns-3 gap-4">
  <div class="mb-4 h-24 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[pink] p-4">1</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-32 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[tomato] p-4">2</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-36 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[skyblue] p-4">3</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-32 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[gold] p-4">4</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-16 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[violet] p-4">5</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-32 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[lightcoral] p-4">5</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-16 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[royalblue] p-4">6</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-64 break-inside-avoid rounded-xl bg-[lightgreen] p-4">7</div>
</div>

Result: https://play.tailwindcss.com/7teTDt3LMZ


You can make three grid columns and put elements inside each of those:
The height attributes are added to simulate longer amounts of text or larger sized content, you can remove it and it should still function the same
<div class="grid grid-cols-3">
  <div>
    <div class="m-4 mr-2 bg-green-200" style="height: 150px">Box 1 here</div>
    <div class="m-4 mr-2 bg-blue-200" style="height: 200px;">Box 2 here</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="m-4 mx-2 bg-yellow-200" style="height: 300px">Box 3 here</div>
    <div class="m-4 mx-2 bg-red-200" style="height: 400px;">Box 4 here</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="m-4 ml-2 bg-pink-200" style="height: 250px">Box 5 here</div>
    <div class="m-4 ml-2 bg-purple-200" style="height: 200px;">Box 6 here</div>
  </div>
</div>



https://play.tailwindcss.com/XvhOwesYEN

One way is to make a parent div flex with flex-row & wrap the inner three div in.
<div class="flex flex-row">
    <div class="">
      <Box 1/>
      <Box 2/>
      <Box 3/>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <Box 4/>
      <Box 5/>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <Box 6/>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>

